# Sort a list by number and by name

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I'm working on a personal project and I got stuck at a certain point.
I have a list of lists that contains 2 elements each in char format. I want to sort each list by number, and then if there are 2 equal numbers in different lists, sort them by alphabet.

Comment: The second item is not a number, it is a string as well... So that means `"10"` is less than `"2"`.

Comment: You probably want to use a list of tuples `[(String, Double)]` instead of a list of lists, since the latter doesn’t specify the length of the inner lists and doesn’t allow the two items to have different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is an instance of an `Ord` where it first sorts on the first item, in case of a tie on the second item, etc.

We can work with [**`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) to sort the elements based on the result of a function call on these items.

We thus can sort with:

```
import Data.List(sortOn)

sortOn (\(x : y : _) -> (read y :: Double, x)) mylist
```

for the given sample data, this will produce:

```
Prelude Data.List> sortOn (\(x : y : _) -> (read y :: Double, x)) mylist
[["Elise","0.9"],["Name","1.2"],["Rex","1.2"],["Diana","2.1"],["Mark","2.1"]]
```

That being said, the above is not very safe, since it is not said that each list has at least two items, nor that the second item can be converted to a `Double`.